# Deleting rows using join within MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, crud, sql-delete

I have written the following query to delete rows but getting `unexpected syntax error`

```
delete from table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON
T1.column1 = T1.column2
where T2.date >  '2001-01-16'
```

Please let me know the correct syntax

Comment: What records do you want to delete? From both tables, the first one or the joined one?

Comment: from just one table `table1`

Comment: Then use the query of the answer. You have to define which table in `delete t1 from ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`delete T1 from table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON
T1.column1 = T1.column2
where T2.date >  '2001-01-16'`